# Using Laravel forms to add data to separate tables with the same data set

Tags: php, laravel

I am a Laravel newbie developer, I'm working on a Laravel project and need to create a form that collects user data and saves it to both a users table(name, user,password) and a profiles(address,phone number) table, with the profile data linked to the user data. I'm not sure how to handle the form submission in my controller to save the data to both tables and link the profile data to the user data when I want to call it. Any help or guidance on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!

The full methods will be great but any outsource link to learn is good enough. Thank you so much

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Honestly, I've tried a million different ways to make it work, but I just kept running into errors for like two straight days. So I'm throwing in the towel and starting fresh, haha. But thanks anyway!